# How to upload a file using dhtmlx uploader

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx uploader in my application. I want to upload single/multiple files and uploaded file name and content I have to save it in database. In .cshtml file I've implemented like

```
   var myForm, 
    formData;
    formData = [{
            type: "fieldset",
            label: "Uploader",
            list: [{
                type: "upload",
                name: "myFiles",
                inputWidth: 330,
                url: "/Home/AddFile",
                }]
        }];
            myForm = new dhtmlXForm("myForm", formData);
```

How can I save the uploaded file in database with content and name?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="partmasterform">
<div id="myForm" style="position: relative; top: 20px;width: 100%; height: 700px; aborder: #B5CDE4 1px solid;"></div>
</form>
```

in your Action Class,

```
File files[] = request.getAllFiles();
```

Then you have to read the file and store the content to db.